# Composition combining data and functions with interfaces and structs

Tags: go, composition

I'm wondering if this is something that's done in Go or if I'm thinking about it all wrong: composing `type x interface` and `type x struct` so my interface methods have access to specific data too:

The C programmer in my wants to do this:

```
type PluginHandler interface {
    onLoad()
    pm *PluginManager
}
func (ph PluginHandler) onLoad() {
    pm.DoSomething()
}
```

There I have an interface defined with a function, but also some data I want to pass to those functions but this is a syntax error.

So is this something that's doable in Go through some other method or am I just thinking about the problem wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `onLoad` incorrectly. You cannot define a function directly on interface type.

Once you have an interface, you need another type to implement methods specified in the interface. For example, if another type implements `onLoad` method, they automatically (implicitly) implement the interface `PluginHandler`.

The other thing you need to do is change the interface function type to accept the required data:

```
type PluginHandler interface {
    onLoad(*PluginManager)
}

struct SomeType {
    // ...
}

func (s SomeType) onLoad(pm *PluginManager) { // SomeType now implements
    pm.DoSomething()                          // PluginHandler interface.
}
```

This way, you get to inject whichever `PluginManager` required by `PluginHandler`.

Also, you can use `SomeType` as a `PluginHandler` type whereever required.

```
func someFuntion(ph PluginHandler) {
    // ...
    ph.onLoad(pm)
    // ...
}
```

Can be called with an input argument of type `SomeType`:

```
s := SomeType{}
someFunction(s)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. I've now got a drop-in plugin system for my app :)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** There is no direct translation to Go.

Long answer:

Go interfaces are *only* methods.

Go structs are *only* data (with the possibility of receiver methods).

You can reference, and even embed interfaces within structs:

```
type Frobnicator interface {
    Frobnicate() error
}

type Widget struct {
    Frobnicator
    WidgetName string
}
```

But that's not really what you're talking about.

The best answer to your dilema is, I believe:  Take a step back.  You're focusing on the trees, and you need to look at the forest.  Go takes a different approach than C, or classical OO languages like C++ and Java.

Look at the general problem to be solved, and find solutions to that in Go. This can be a painful process (I can say from experience), but it's really the only way to learn the new way of thinking.

Comment: can you please point to some reference or handy book to read about how the OO philosophy fits into golang?.  We shall agree that the OO philosophy is not attached to any language as it shall be recognized as mental tool for studying and defining components and their relations on a system, all of that in favor of reaching the **right abstractions**.

Comment: As you mention golang promotes to think in his particular way.. but not totally different from the OO-world. For example: the concept of interface is exactly the same as it was in java (prior to version 8)... but the polymorphism is restricted to work interfaces only (in java you could get to it using classes as well). And, also, structs has no hierarchy.. they do have struct embeding for favor code re use, but that is not hierarchy.... anyway.. i'm starting to re-think somethings...

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of reference you want. Go is intentionally and expressly _not_ an OO language. It does have some characteristics common among OO languages, and therefore can accomplish some of the same tasks by some of the same means. But that doesn't make it an OO language.

Comment: As you stated golang has part of its philosophy laying on top of the OO principles and working with interfaces in golang is very different from java. For start there is no need of impliciting declaring an abstraction implements an interface, oppossed to java (you need to type "implements someInterfaceIdentifier". For second, in java the suffix "able" was the recomended term to use with interfaces, in golang the suffix recommened is "er|or". THe first one is perphahs describling the object in a *passive* way, the latter in an *active* way. (Readable vs Sourcer, both thing acts a source)

Comment: And i have more half-baked thoughts... and would like to know deeper about it... i probably need someone to talk to about this and make "oo-based therapy". Probably see some designs on simple scenarios that favor code re use employing the right golang-mechanishs, (i mean the building blocks that the language provide). (for example, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49326675/903998, when you got time...)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, you can add extra methods to an existing type, by introducing another (indirection) type as:

```
type HandlerManager PluginManager

func (x *HandlerManager) onLoad() {
    ((*PluginManager)(x)).DoSomething()
}
```

And if you need to go with a more generic solution, a combination of Adapter & Strategy patterns could do:

```
type PluginHandlerAdapter struct{ _onLoad func() }

func (x *PluginHandlerAdapter) onLoad() {
    x._onLoad()
}
```

Used like (public/private access ignored):

```
type PluginManager struct {
    PluginHandlerAdapter
}

func NewPluginManager() *PluginManager {
    res := new(PluginManager)
    res._onLoad = res.DoSomething
    return res
}
```